# Keep windows from jumping workspaces when they request focus

Tags: 10.04, focus

When a window requests focus while it is on a different workspace, it will jump to my current workspace.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is it possible to Minimize them (i mean, are they regular, non-modal windows)? Im almost sure minimized windows do not jump works workspades

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of using different workspaces - if I need to minimize what I'm working on before switching to the other workspace, I might as well, just use 1 workspace and minimize back and forth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Settings Manager -> Windows Tweaks -> Focus tab.

There is a setting for what to do when a window raises itself.

Comment: Only trouble is, you don't say where "Settings" is. I have Applications, Places, and System, and under each of those various other choices -- but no "Settings". Any hints?

Comment: @user2532531 What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user2532531 This question is for Ubuntu 10.04, which almost certainly is not what you're using.  Also, if I remember correctly, I was using xubuntu, not straight ubuntu, although I didn't tag that into the ticket.  At this point, I'm using xubuntu 12.04, and the above answer still applies to xubuntu 12.04